# Use of TCP/IP Protocol under ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am kind of new in ROS (well … finished the turtlesim tutorial though :-D…) and currently trying to get functional a new stack to control an arm-robot through TCP/IP.

I understand that ROS allows us to communicate using the TCP/IP protocol and that there is some kind of library called TCPROS which can be implemented to do so (explained in http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/TCPROS.

I was wondering if anybody already implemented it, or if there were any existing packages I could get inspiration from.

Cheers,

Gael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9462/use-of-tcp/ip-protocol-under-ros/) by [Gael](https://answers.ros.org/users/308/gael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of the ROS client libraries (e.g. roscpp, rospy) implement this protocol for you.  I probably wouldn't recommend reimplementing TCPROS as first step in getting used to ROS.  You should be able to write a program using one of the client libraries.

FYI: I would also look for existing packages that may already implement drivers for your hardware here:

http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gael](https://answers.ros.org/users/308/gael/) on 2011-03-17**:
I did not know the protocol was implemented in roscpp library. Is there any information about this you could give me ?

**Comment by [Gael](https://answers.ros.org/users/308/gael/) on 2011-03-17**:
We are currently working on the hardware part, so I don't think there is any packages that have been implemented to control our hardware. Anyway i'm sur there are already packages already implemented to allow TCP/IP communication. I cannot find any of those.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you describe your setup a little bit more? Do you have a embedded board or PC on connected to the arm and you want to connect to it from a different PC ([similar question)](http://answers.ros.org/question/331/subscriber-over-ip)? Or is the communication protocol of the low-level arm interface based on a TCP/IP communication protocol (like KUKA FRI for example)?

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gael](https://answers.ros.org/users/308/gael/) on 2011-03-17**:
The ROS GUI is running on the host PC (Ubuntu). The Targets are a couple of Embedded Boards (DSPs which control the arm), all communicating with the host PC through a hub using TCP/IP. I'm interrest to implement the ROS part of the TCP/IP communication.